# Incrementing a number based on number of zeroes

Tags: bash

I want to have a string composed of `"1234567890"` repeating up to length `72`.  And another string of same length with the non-zero digits.  Whilst instead of the digit zero, I get an incrementing number starting from `1`.

Thus for the string

```
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
```

I get the following printed result

```
         1         2         3         4
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

I want to do this up to length `72`

Have started with removing non-zero values with a space, but incrementing the index at the positions of `0` is a real problem.

```
  wz="1234567890"  # Basic measure of ten
  hg="${wz}${wz}${wz}${wz}${wz}${wz}${wz}12"
  
  ha=${hg//[123456789]/" "}

  printf '%s\n' "$ha"
  printf '%s\n' "$hg"
```

Comment: Why do you want a program or script to produce these simple strings? You can type them in which much less work.

Comment: I want the ability to dynamically generate the pattern for user defined lengths. Rather than hardwire a specific solution.

Comment: You might find inspiration in this one-liner I once felt myself inclined to write. It is for a reverse-numbered ruler: `l=0+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1+ l=$l$l$l l=${l//+/-+-} l=${l//-/....}`

Comment: The upper ruler is even simpler: `echo "        "{1..7}` (8 spaces, echo will add the 9th)

Comment: Oh yes, the variable length: `length=72 ruler=yourcode ruler="${ruler::$length}"`, with a ruler of ample length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function makes the required repeats (up to 200 chars), then truncates them according to the argument.

```
#! /bin/bash

Ruler () {  # (lth)

    local Tens Digs j

    printf -v Tens '%10d' {1..20}
    for (( j = 1; j <= 20; j++)); do Digs="${Digs}1234567890"; done
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "${Tens:0:${1}}" "${Digs:0:${1}}"
}

    Ruler 72
    Ruler 32
```

Like this:

```
$ ./Hdsup
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7  
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
         1         2         3  
12345678901234567890123456789012
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` program would produce two "rulers", each consisting of a line of digits. The *second* line will be numbered from 1 to 10 (with 0 taking the place of 10) with no intermediate spacing between the digits.  The first line will be numbered similarly but with some spacing between each digit.

The program takes two optional command-line arguments.  The first argument is the total width of the second ruler (80 by default), while the second argument is the step size, or tab width, of the numbering of the first ruler (8 by default, as this is the common tab width on Unix terminals).

Example runs:

```bash
$ ./ruler
       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
$ ./ruler 72
       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
$ ./ruler 72 10
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
$ ./ruler 122 6
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```

The `ruler` script:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        width = ARGC >= 2 ? ARGV[1] : 80
        step  = ARGC >= 3 ? ARGV[2] : 8

        while (++i <= width) {
                if (i%step == 0) line1 = line1 sprintf("%*s", step, (i/step)%10)
                line2 = line2 (i%10)
        }

        print line1
        print line2
}
```

This essentially adds the next digit to the `line2` string (the second ruler) in each iteration of the `while` loop, while adding a right-adjusted field of width `step` with a digit to the `line1` string (the first ruler) every `step` iteration.

There is no width restriction in this code, and no sanitation or validation of the command line arguments.